# Error while publish laravel 10 web application on mdb go cli

Tags: laravel

I am trying to publish my laravel 10 web application to mdb go using mdb cli. I ran the `mdb publish -p php-laravel` cmd from root dir but i am getting error and a warning

**Warning** This is not MDB JARV project and there is no guarantee that it will work properly after publishing. In case of problems, please write to our support https://mdbootstrap.com/support/.

**Error** Could not publish: Build folder not found.

I want to publish/deploy laravel 10 web application on mdb go using mdb go cli

Comment: googled your error, did you try this: https://mdbootstrap.com/support/cli/error-found-when-publishing/

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth i have tried this command but I am facing same issue